# Accessing Nested Arrays in JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins, rss, multidimensional-array

I'm sure this is a simple problem, so my apologies in advance for even asking it.  In the code below, I'm converting an RSS feed to JSON using the jGFeed plugin.  Within this JSON, I need to access a URL node that is nested several levels deep, inside a nested array.  Right now, I'm able to use "console.log("feeds.entries[i]")" to get some attributes of each object at the parent level (i.e., "title", "content", etc.).  I just can't figure out how to drill down into the nested array.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.jGFeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/solidverbal/app', function(feeds){
        // Check for errors
        if(!feeds){
        // there was an error
        return false;
        }
        var sAnchors = "<ul>";
        //var wantedFeed = "";
        for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
            console.log(feeds.entries[i]); 
            var sAnchors = sAnchors + "<li><a href=\"#link\" id=\"title_" + i + "\" class=\"giveFeeds\">" + feeds.entries[i].title + "</a></li>";
        }
        sAnchors = sAnchors + '</ul>';

        //Append the <a>.
        $('#titles').append(sAnchors);

        //When the user clicks on the giveFeeds link....
        $('.giveFeeds').live('click', function(e) {

            //Get the feed number
            var tmpId = $(e.target).attr("id");

            //Returns the value after the '_' char and make sure it returns de number.
            var id = parseInt(tmpId.split("_")[1]);

            //Use the id value to get the desired feed
            var wantedFeed = feeds.entries[id].content;

            //Then do whatever you want with that entry
            $("#content").html(wantedFeed);
        });


    }, 20);
});
```

Here is an example of the JSON structure as it appears within the Chrome console:

```
Object
     author: "Test"
     categories: Array[10]
     content: "<p></p><p>Test Content"
     contentSnippet: "Test Content Snippet"
     link: "http://www.solidverbal.com/2011/03/24/charles-robinson-324/"
     mediaGroups: Array[1]
          0: Object
               contents: Array[1]
                    0: Object
                         fileSize: "12796261"
                         type: "audio/mpeg"
                         url: "http://www.testurl/test.mp3"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm thinking it's a nested for-loop or something, but for whatever reason I just can't get it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just like navigating the object graph in Java or C#, you can do `feeds.entries[0].link` to get the Url or `feeds.entries[0].mediaGroups[0].contents[0].fileSize`

```
for (var i = 0; i < feeds.entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = feeds.entries[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < entry.mediaGroups.length; j++) {
        var mediaGroup = entry.mediaGroup[j];
        for (var k = 0; k < mediaGroup.contents.length; k++) {
            var content = mediaGroup.contents[k];
            // do something with content.url.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Carlos, that was actually the first thing I tried, but the page wasn't displaying and Chrome's console was throwing an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Actually, it does work when I put the "0" in manually, but if I put an "i" in the brackets, I'm getting the TypeError.  I'd like to get all the links, not just that one...

Comment: Can you post your full code somewhere? I don't really see any problems whatsoever...

Comment: http://www.solidverbal.com/app/test.html

View in Chrome, check the Console.  Looks like a blank page, but you'll see what's going on if you view the Console.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is that the name of the attribute is `mediaGroups` not `mediagroups`. Sorry it was a typo on my part.

Comment: I updated my code... you'll see, though, if I put in an "i" instead of a 0, the page doesn't render and an error is thrown...

Comment: Also worth noting... the feeds.entries[0].link is a different location than the one located underneath mediaGroups.  with jGFeed, the RSS enclosure gets put under mediaGroups, whereas the regular "link" is something else.

Comment: Ok, so the problem you are having with the new code is that you are iterating the feeds entries mediaGroups and contents with the same index (`i`), so for example your page retrieves 19 entries, but that doesn't mean that each entry will have 19 mediaGroups nor 19 contents. You'll need to use nested `for` loops to iterate effectively through all urls. I'm updating my answer to show that.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much.  If I had any reputation I'd vote your answer up about 25 times.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate of each item jQuery's `$.each()` might be able to help you achieve your goal.

```
$.each(feed.mediaGroups, function(x, mediaGroup) {

    $.each(mediaGroup, function(y, contents) {

        $.each(contents, function(z, content){
            alert(content.fileSize);
        });
    });
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/7CwLs/1/).**

Comment: This is good to know, although I'm not entirely sure how to get this working with my code since I'm using jGFeed and not generating the feed like you are on the jsfiddle example.